# How can I store UI details in URL parameters?

Tags: angular, routes

With Angular, I have two URLs to display pages.

- app/students/list --- Display a list of students
- app/students/:id --- Display details of student whose ID is id

Let's say I have dynamic tabs. When I click one of students from the list, a new tab with this student details will be open. 
So When I call app/students/list, the following will be displayed.

[image]

When I click Sam, call app/students/2 and a new tab will be open with Sam's details.

[image]

I can click Student List tab and click Sally to open a new tab for Sally's details so on...

But if I refresh with the page after I click Sam and Sam's details is displayed, Student List will be disappeared. 
How can I include tabs status in URL and when refreshing the current url, display same tab status (Student List tab and Sam's tab will be appeared)

Comment: I wouldn't store that in the URL at all, this kind of "workspace" state should probably be in local or sessions storage.

Answer (score 0):

complete working demo of [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4cou9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.component.html)..

If you want to preserve state when page reloads, you can use angular router. I am here not going to implementing dynamic part of tabs. this event is fire when clicking on particular row of Student List...

```
clickRow(index, tabGroup){
     this.rowData = this.studentService.studentsData.filter( data => data.id === index + 1 );
     this.rowData = {...this.rowData[0]};

     tabGroup.selectedIndex = 1
     this.router.navigate(['student', {queryParams: JSON.stringify( this.rowData) }]);
}
```

and then you can get data on page reload like this...

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.studentData = this.studentService.studentsData;
   this.activatedRouter.params.subscribe(data =>{
     this.rowData = JSON.parse(data['queryParams'])
   })
}
```